# Using Exported values

Tags: aws-cloudformation

I am able to export the keys using this cloudformation template...

https://github.com/shantanuo/cloudformation/blob/master/restricted.template.txt

But how do I import the saved keys directly into "UserData" section of another template? I tried this, but does not work...

```
aws-ec2-assign-elastic-ip --access-key !Ref {"Fn::ImportValue" : "accessKey" } --secret-key --valid-ips 35.174.198.170
```

The rest of the template (without access and secret key reference) is working as expected.

https://github.com/shantanuo/cloudformation/blob/master/security.template2.txt

Comment: Can you show your userdata section including your importvalue section

Comment: @WarrenG Yes. It is mentioned in the second github link. The question is can I import value using this:  !Ref {"Fn::ImportValue" : "accessKey" }

Comment: What happens when you try it

Comment: Template validation error: Template format error: JSON not well-formed. (line 64, column 59)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, if this is your script that does the export (sorry, this one is in yaml)

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Metadata:
  License: Apache-2.0
Description: 'AWS CloudFormation Sample Template'

Parameters:
  NewUsername:
    NoEcho: 'false'
    Type: String
    Description: New account username
    MinLength: '1'
    MaxLength: '41'
    ConstraintDescription: the username must be between 1 and 41 characters
  Password:
    NoEcho: 'true'
    Type: String
    Description: New account password
    MinLength: '1'
    MaxLength: '41'
    ConstraintDescription: the password must be between 1 and 41 characters

Resources:
  CFNUser:
    Type: AWS::IAM::User
    Properties:
      LoginProfile:
        Password: !Ref 'Password'
      UserName : !Ref 'NewUsername'
  CFNAdminGroup:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Group
  Admins:
    Type: AWS::IAM::UserToGroupAddition
    Properties:
      GroupName: !Ref 'CFNAdminGroup'
      Users: [!Ref 'CFNUser']
  CFNAdminPolicies:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Policy
    Properties:
      PolicyName: CFNAdmins
      PolicyDocument:
        Statement:
        - Effect: Allow
          Action: '*'
          Resource: '*'
          Condition:
            StringEquals:
              aws:RequestedRegion:
              - ap-south-1
              - us-east-1
      Groups: [!Ref 'CFNAdminGroup']
  CFNKeys:
    Type: AWS::IAM::AccessKey
    Properties:
      UserName: !Ref 'CFNUser'

Outputs:
  AccessKey:
    Value: !Ref 'CFNKeys'
    Description: AWSAccessKeyId of new user
    Export:
      Name: 'accessKey'
  SecretKey:
    Value: !GetAtt [CFNKeys, SecretAccessKey]
    Description: AWSSecretAccessKey of new user
    Export:
      Name: 'secretKey'
```

Then here is an example of how you would import those values in userdata in the import cloudformation script:

```
{
  "AWSTemplateFormatVersion": "2010-09-09",
  "Description": "Test instance stack",
  "Parameters": {
    "KeyName": {
      "Description": "The EC2 Key Pair to allow SSH access to the instance",
      "Type": "AWS::EC2::KeyPair::KeyName"
    },
    "BaseImage": {
      "Description": "The AMI to use for machines.",
      "Type": "String"
    },
    "VPCID": {
      "Description": "ID of the VPC",
      "Type": "String"
    },
    "SubnetID": {
      "Description": "ID of the subnet",
      "Type": "String"
    }
  },
  "Resources": {
    "InstanceSecGrp": {
      "Type": "AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup",
      "Properties": {
        "GroupDescription": "Instance Security Group",
        "SecurityGroupIngress": [{
          "IpProtocol": "-1",
          "CidrIp": "0.0.0.0/0"
        }],
        "SecurityGroupEgress": [{
          "IpProtocol": "-1",
          "CidrIp": "0.0.0.0/0"
        }],
        "VpcId": {
          "Ref": "VPCID"
        }
      }
    },
    "SingleInstance": {
      "Type": "AWS::EC2::Instance",
      "Properties": {
        "KeyName": {
          "Ref": "KeyName"
        },
        "ImageId": {
          "Ref": "BaseImage"
        },
        "InstanceType": "t2.micro",
        "Monitoring": "false",
        "BlockDeviceMappings": [{
          "DeviceName": "/dev/xvda",
          "Ebs": {
            "VolumeSize": "20",
            "VolumeType": "gp2"
          }
        }],
        "NetworkInterfaces": [{
          "GroupSet": [{
            "Ref": "InstanceSecGrp"
          }],
          "AssociatePublicIpAddress": "true",
          "DeviceIndex": "0",
          "DeleteOnTermination": "true",
          "SubnetId": {
            "Ref": "SubnetID"
          }
        }],
        "UserData": {
          "Fn::Base64": {
            "Fn::Join": ["", [
              "#!/bin/bash -xe\n",
              "yum install httpd -y\n",
              "sudo sh -c \"echo ",
              { "Fn::ImportValue" : "secretKey" },
              " >> /home/ec2-user/mysecret.txt\" \n",
              "sudo sh -c \"echo ",
              { "Fn::ImportValue" : "accessKey" },
              " >> /home/ec2-user/myaccesskey.txt\" \n"
            ]]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

In this example I am just echoing the value of the import into a file. If you ssh onto the SingleInstance and check the logs at `/var/lib/cloud/instance/scripts/part-001` then you will see what the user data script looks like on the server itself. In my case the contents of that file is (values aren't real for the keys):

```
#!/bin/bash -xe
yum install httpd -y
sudo sh -c "echo hAc7/TJA123143235ASFFgKWkKSjIC4 >> /home/ec2-user/mysecret.txt"
sudo sh -c "echo AKIAQ123456789123D >> /home/ec2-user/myaccesskey.txt"
```

Using this as a starting point you can do whatever you need to with the import value.

I've tested all of this with the exact scripts above and it all works.

Comment: Both the templates are working as expected. But will you suggest any optimization?

Comment: It's not a good idea to have any keys in your userdata, because anyone with console access or access to the server can view your key. In the 1st template I would save the key to secrets manager (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-secretsmanager-secret.html), and in the second template I would do an aws cli command to get the secret value (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/secretsmanager/get-secret-value.html).

Comment: ok. got it. Apart from secret key, is there anything else you would do differently?

Answer (score 0):

What is suggested in the comments seems to be correct. I can directly refer to the name (for e.g. 'accessKey' in this case) using ImportValue!

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Metadata:
  License: Apache-2.0
Description: 'AWS CloudFormation Sample Template'

Resources:
  CFNUser:
    Type: AWS::IAM::User

Outputs:
  AccessKey:
    Value: 
      Fn::ImportValue: accessKey
    Description: AWSAccessKeyId of new user
```

For e.g. the above template will return the value of accessKey if it is already exported by some other template.

Comment: Though this code works, I am not able to refer to the accessKey in user data.

Comment: What happens when you try?

Comment: Getting an error: Template validation error: Template format error: JSON not well-formed. (line 64, column 59)

Comment: Do you want to use Json or can I give you an example in yaml

Comment: JSON is preferred. Something like this. But do not work. 
https://medium.com/pablo-perez/how-do-i-import-a-stack-export-value-within-userdata-in-another-stack-9084b206897d